# Depth of IBM MQ queue

Tags: java, ssl, ibm-mq

Can you please help me, I am trying to find the ibm mq depth over SSL channel.

```
Security.setProperty("ssl.SocketFactory.provider",
        "com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketFactoryImpl");
Security.setProperty("ssl.ServerSocketFactory.provider",
        "com.ibm.jsse2.SSLServerSocketFactoryImpl");

System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "abcd.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword",
        "abcd");

System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "abcd.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword",
    "abcd");


int openOptions = MQC.MQOO_INQUIRE + MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF;

MQEnvironment.hostname = "test";
MQEnvironment.port = 1234;
MQEnvironment.channel = "test";

MQEnvironment.sslCipherSuite = "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA";

MQEnvironment.properties.put(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY,
        MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT);

MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager("test");

MQQueue destQueue = qMgr.accessQueue("TEST.ERROR",   openOptions);
System.out.println("TEST.ERROR size:" + destQueue.getCurrentDepth());
destQueue.close();
qMgr.disconnect();


        } catch (MQException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

When I try to run this code, I got the following exception:

MQJE001: Completion Code 1, Reason 2068

Answer (score 2):

The reason code 2068 [clearly states](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21179685) that you are trying to get the depth of a remote queue. You can't - it's on a different box. You have to connect to the queue manager where your `TEST.ERROR` queue is local.